# How to determine whether a Class is inherited from another Class?

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection

I'd like to know if there is an easy and elegant way to determine whether a `Class` object has an inheritance relationship to another.

All I found in the documentation is `getSuperclass()`, which gives the super class of a `Class` object. All I can come up with is this:

```
public static boolean isInherited(Class child, Class parent) {
    for (Class type = child; type != null; type = type.getSuperclass()) {
        if (type.equals(parent)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Am I missing out on something?

**Edit**

The reason behind this is, that I am writing a ReST-Service to retrieve some insights on given objects. Therefore the type is provided as `String` which I take to retrieve a `Class` via `Class.forName`. All classes available for this extra insights are derived from one base class, which is available for insights as well.

Comment: Can you share with us the reason why you need this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't know why you want to know whether a class inherits from another, but your solution looks fine. Also, `isAssignableFrom` is not suitable for this job because it accounts for interfaces' implementation. If class `A` implements the interface `B`, `B` is assignable from `A` but `A` does not inherit from `B`.

There is a tiny problem with your approach though, passing the same class to both parameters returns true, which is incorrect because the same class cannot inherit from itself. You can solve this simply by checking whether the two arguments are equal.

Another thing you might want to consider is super interfaces.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, the equality for same classes. This is intended behaviour, but I forgot to mention this in my question.

Comment: @T.Grottker Well then I think your implementation is ok.

Comment: Could you elaborate more, why `isAssignableFrom()` doesn't suite?

Comment: Let's say class `A` implements an interface called `B`. `A.class` and `B.class` don't have an inheritance relationship. `A` certainly does not inherit from `B`. However, if you call `B.class.isAssignableFrom(A.class)` it will return true, which I think is not your intended behaviour @T.Grottker

Answer (score 2):

Use [Class.isAssignableFrom()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)).